# Case Creation Template not firing when a case is created using email to case

Tags: case, email2case

I have enabled email-to-case in Salesforce. When receiving an email a case is created with the assignment of an account and contract.

I have created an HTML email template and letterhead, made it Available for Use, and specified the template in Case Support Settings on the "Case Create Template". I tested the template with a same case and it looks great.

But, for some reason, when a new case is created, it is not being sent to the contact on the case.

[image]

What additional settings should I check/verify to make sure the case contact gets an email when the case is created?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you created auto response rules on case creation?

Comment: @JayantDas no I have not, but I have never had to create an auto-response rule before for this to work. I simply populated this Support Settings templates, and and used the default. If you have to create an auto-response rule, what are these Support Settings default templates for?

Comment: I have provided some details in answer. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your information in the comments:

> I simply populated this Support Settings templates, and and used the default. If you have to create an auto-response rule, what are these Support Settings default templates for?

The template configured in the support settings is used when an agent manually creates a case and selects an email to be sent. The definition of this setting on the [help article](https://support.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_supportrules.htm&type=5) is as:

> The template used to notify contacts that their case was created manually by a support agent. The notification is optional; it's triggered by a checkbox on the case edit page. This template must be Available for Use.

The option to use the template that's configured in the support settings is available on new case creation screen in optional section and looks like below.
[image]

However, if you would like an email to be sent out immediately after a customer sends an email to create a case, you will need to configure auto response rule. An auto-response rule by definition is:

> Send automatic email responses to lead or case submissions based on the record’s attributes. Set up auto-response rules to send quick replies to customers to let them know someone at your company received their inquiry or details about their issue.

While configuring the auto-response rule, you can still use the same template that's configured in your support settings. You can find more on how to configure auto-response rules on the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=creating_auto-response_rules.htm&type=5).